# Make fetchmail leave mail on server for a specified period of time?

Tags: fetchmail

I know that fetchmail can be configured to leave mail on the server (usually done with the `keep uidl` keyword combination), but is there a way to configure it to leave mail on the server *for a specified minimum period of time* and delete them thereafter?

For example, suppose I want messages to remain on the server for 48 hours after they have been downloaded, and then be deleted on the next fetchmail invocation against that server.

I am mostly interested in solutions that work with POP3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short: it doesn't do that.

Long: fetchmail is only designed to do one of these:

- read *entire* mailboxes, or
- read the *unread* messages from a mailbox

When it has read a message, it can mark this (on the server) as "read".  But there is no timestamp associated with this.

The inability to do this is known, and according to a reply on [fetchmail users](https://sourceforge.net/p/fetchmail/mailman/message/32532848/) by by [Rob MacGregor](https://sourceforge.net/p/fetchmail/git/ci/4a209c8320c6704381f8e577ea833f01f6360132/), [probably an FAQ](https://sourceforge.net/p/fetchmail/mailman/message/32532850/):

- [Re: [fetchmail-users] Fetch only messages marked as seen](https://sourceforge.net/p/fetchmail/mailman/message/32532848/)

> That'll be because that's not what Fetchmail was designed to do.
>   Fetchmail is designed to download entire mailboxes or at least the
>   unread messages.  Without changes to the source there's no way to
>   download only the seen email.
>
> It also doesn't delete email after N days (I'm pretty sure that's in
>   the FAQ - it certainly used to be).

Answer (score 0):

getmail is the solution, in your case. https://pyropus.ca/software/getmail
The linux program getmail can fetch INBOX and/or other folders (in case of IMAP protocol), with or without SSL, and delete email after N days.

Example of getmailrc file, placed in ~/.getmail directory:

```
[retriever]
type = SimpleIMAPSSLRetriever
server = IMAP_SERVER_CHANGEME
port = 993
username = USERNAME_CHANGEME
password = PASSWORD_CHANGEME
mailboxes = ("INBOX","Junk",)

[destination]
type = Maildir
path = ~/Maildir/

[options]
message_log_syslog = true
message_log_verbose = true
# retrieve only new emails
read_all = false
# delete on server after x days
delete_after = 6
# do not add a Delivered-To: header field
delivered_to = false
# do not add a Received: header field
received = false
```